# height 100% doesnt' work

Tags: html, css

I made website and code structure is here.

```
<body>
   <header></header>
   <section></section>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

In `<section>`, I define `height: 100%` but it doesn't work properly.

Detailed section tag is here.

```
<section>
   <div class="section-home">
      <div class="menubox">1</div>
      <div class="menubox">1</div>
      <div class="menubox">1</div>
      <div class="menubox">1</div>
      <div class="menubox">1</div>
      <div class="menubox">1</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

When I create lots of .box, it overflow  like this.

[image]

( `<section>` tag's backgroud-color is light gray and `footer` is white)

[css]

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.section-home {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}
.menubox {
    height: 350px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 0px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px lightgray;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px lightgray;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px lightgray;
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: (350px * 6) is probably > 100% of that container, so it adds height to adjust ..

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I think so too. So, is there any solution about this?

Comment: consider min-height for your section instead .. or simply don't use height at all, keep it auto

Comment: @TemaniAfif I modified html, body: height: 100% to height: auto, it works perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: no need to modify, simply remove it ;) because by default it's auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change height to min-height.

```
section {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

replace to ->

```
html, body {
    height: auto;
}
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Removing height in `.section-home` solves the problem

```
 .section-home {
            display: flex;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            /*height: 100%;*/
        }
```